# Overlay Flutter app over other installed apps

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm creating an app lock using Flutter. I want the lock screen to overlay over other selected apps from the list of installed apps.

I'm allowing display over other apps. But when I open the selected apps in my device, it doesn't show the unlock screen. How can I resolve this ? Or, which plugin I can use to do so ?

Currently I'm using following plugins:

1. Flutter overlay apps to create overlay screen.
2. permission handler to handle app permission
3. device apps to get the installed apps

Comment: This question is too broad to answer, hundreds of things could be going wrong. Troubleshoot the problem further to narrow it down to a specific problem, or provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.